# Drawing the deleted comb space

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm interesting to draw the [deleted comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space) using `tikz` package, but my skills don't go so far, so I'd like to ask you the solution.

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! can you illustrate with some sketch what you like to do?

Comment: I notice now that the posted picture has the problem with a blue rectangle at left side being a bit too tall; I deduce that posted picture was originally created in TikZ and erroneously did some `\draw[fill=blue,color=blue] <rectangle spec>;` as in my first posted code. I later corrected my mistake to use `\fill` rather.

Answer (score 6):

And I didn't even open the TikZ manual, it was "automatic writing" as if part of my brain was assimilating the syntax only by being too frequently here.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
  \draw (0,0)--(1.2,0)--(1.2,1.2)--(0,1.2)--cycle;
  \draw[color=blue, very thick] (1,0)--(1,1);
  \draw[color=blue, very thick]  (1/2,0)--(1/2,1);
  \draw[color=blue, very thick]  (1/3,0)--(1/3,1);
  \foreach \x in {4, ..., 20}
   \draw[color=blue, very thick]  (1/\x,0)--(1/\x,1);
  \fill[color=blue]  (1/20,0)--(1/20,1)--(0,1)--(0,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course it is lacking in some decoration, but that's I hope not the point of the OP.

[image]